# How to handle multiple asynctasks while rotating screen?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have got an Activity which can run different asynctasks. Under rare circumstances, it might be possible that all asynctasks could be called  at the same time. Ok, not really at the same time, but ms after the first on get called - lets say one after the other.

Every asynctask does show a progress bar. At the time, everything is workin, IF screen orientation is not changedt too fast while asynctasks are running. When I change orientation of screen very fast then the app crashes while doin asynctask one after the other. is there any technique to handle such problem?

Comment: it shouldn't crash if you do things right, so it'd be nice to see *some* code to see what you're doing and the stack trace of the crash.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell why exactly is your app crashing without having your code available here.

Screen rotation causes Activity to be recreated by default. You can change this behavior, but then you must handle all configuration changes by yourself, which is complicated, so developers are discouraged from doing it.

What you should do is to keep reference to all your async tasks in an object that survives activity recreation. This can be very easily done in two ways depending on what approach you want to use:

1. Override `Activity.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` which gets called before activity is destroyed due to orientation change and return the object there. In new activity `onCreate()` call `Activity.getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` to retrieve this object and there you have all your async tasks. This approach is however deprecated since API 13. You should not use it unless you want to avoid using fragments at all cost.
2. Use fragment implementation with no GUI, add it to the fragment manager and call its `setRetainInstance(true)` method, so it will survive orientation change and can later be received using `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()`. And here you have your async tasks again.

In the object you can register current activity as a listener to be notified when async task finishes. This way always the correct activity gets notified when async task finishes. When you use the second approach using fragment, you don't have to explicitly register activity as a listener. The fragment is aware of being attached to new activity when its method `onAttach(Activity)` gets called automatically by fragment manager.

Answer (score 0):

Screen rotate creates another instance of the Activity (it's barbaric, I hate it, they should do that better). So your `AsyncTask` will get confused when the screen rotates. A good practice is to keep a `WeakReference` to whatever you're updating in you `AsyncTask` and check to see that the object is still valid when `onComplete` fires

But that Doesn't help you here, because you want the data to end up at your rotated activity. I'd recommend moving those tasks to an `IntentService`. More info
http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html

Comment: And how do you propose to deliver the result back to the `Activity`, using an `IntentService`? It is not designed to support binding, and if you use an event bus or some other generic notification method, then you might as well implement that in the `AsyncTask` instead of keeping an explicit reference.

Comment: Use the `BroadcastManager`. Since the original activity and the rotated activity are both receivers for the broadcast from the `IntentService` either will get the result and progress updates. The `IntentService` is a better option for this, because it will persist even if the original activity is resource collected.

Comment: The `AsyncTask` will also persist after the original `Activity` is destroyed and garbage collected. It's not dependent on the `Activity` lifecycle, as it is kept around by the thread pool executor and the main thread's `Looper` until it's task is completed and result delivered.